# Como enviar objeto como atributo de outro objeto de uma JSP para um controlador Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Olá, 
Eu tenho uma classe **Noticia** relacionada ManyToOne com uma classe **Secao**. A classe Noticia possui um atributo do tipo Secao (onde ocorre a relação @ManyToOne). Gostaria de saber como faço para, no formulário de cadastro de notícias, enviar a seção a qual ela deverá fazer parte.

Nota: Eu já tenho a lista de seções disponíveis na JSP e o usuário seleciona a seção para a notícia que irá cadastrar através de um campo de seleção. Porém não sei como passar o objeto secao como atributo da notícia que irá ser cadastrada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="secao.atributoDeSecaoQueSeraDefinido">
  <option value="politica">Política</option>
</select>
```

Você pode tentar fazer desta maneira, mas como você já deve ter a seção cadastrada, eu acho que pegando o objeto pronto do formulário não vai fazer o relacionamento. Então você pega apenas o valor da seção que o cara escolheu, busca pelo objeto desta seção e define no objeto notícia.